# htaccess multiple RewriteConds

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

This is my site root

```
/public_html
    beta/
        .htaccess
        public/
            index.php
            .htaccess
```

The first .htaccess inside beta folder is for changing dir from mysite.com/beta to `mysite.com/beta/public`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mysite.com/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !beta/public/
RewriteRule (.*) /beta/public/$1 [L]
```

The other.htaccess inside public folder is for shorten url from `index.php?photo_id=id` to `/id`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?photo_id=$1
```

How can I make these work both since for now only one of them work not together? Thanks

Comment: What URL are you going to and what do you expect it to do?

Comment: from mysite.com/beta/index.php?photo_id=id to mysite.com/beta/id @JonLin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you have "non public" stuff in public_html? If you want it private, shouldn't you place it in a private directory?

Comment: Because the beta folder is just for testing. Supose beta folder as the root folder it is temporary.All files inside beta folder will then be removed inside site root @Julien B

Answer (score 0):

For the beta htaccess file, try removing the absolute URLs

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\)?mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond $1 !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Note that the trailing slash needs to be removed from the HTTP_HOST, there's not slashes in that variable.

For the public folder, also remove the absolute URLs

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?photo_id=$1
```